# Metadata for stackoverflow

Tags: support, data-explorer

I want to view the metadata for the Stack Overflow odata interface, I'm trying the following url to do that,

https://data.stackexchange.com/odata.svc/$metadata.

However, I always end up with following error message "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the address changed. (I'm not too familiar with the OData stuff.)

Try this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/$metadata

If you found the URL you're trying to use somewhere on the site and it's not working, could you please edit your question to tell us where you found it (so it can be removed or fixed)?

Comment: the link posted here works, i.e. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom/$metadata  , i tested it. you might have to copy/paste it though.

Comment: Funny, the link parses fine in comment, but not in post. Markdown again?

Comment: @Balus: Yeah, probably. Interestingly, the edit preview doesn't link *any* of it.